# How to check DB table values in SQL stored procedure with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

May I know how to check the values in a database table when there is no exist data?

I wrote this SQL script and C# code to test the condition statement. But it doesn't work.

In SQL stored procedures I have tried `Select * from Table` and check if the condition is 0

```
DECLARE @CheckFindQTY FLOAT 

SET @CheckFindQTY = (SELECT INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC 
                     WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID 
                       AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION  
                       AND INV_QTY = @INV_QTY)

IF @CheckFindQTY = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @RecordFound = 3
END
```

And also I tried checking if the condition is `NULL`

```
DECLARE @CheckFindQTY FLOAT 

SET @CheckFindQTY = (SELECT INV_QTY 
                     FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC 
                     WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID 
                       AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION  
                       AND INV_QTY = @INV_QTY)

IF @CheckFindQTY = NULL
BEGIN
     SELECT @RecordFound = 3
END
```

Then I query the condition in C# if the condition is == 3 then show alert message

```
int recordFound = Convert.ToInt32(_cmd.Parameters["@RecordFound"].Value);

if (recordFound == 3)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('There is not QTY in Location, please check again!!')", true);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if a record with certain INV_ID, INV_LOCATION and INV_QTY exists?

Comment: Take a look at `ExecuteScalar` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, i want check the certain INV_ID, INV_LOCATION and INV_QTY exists,if there is empty then show alert message

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @CheckFindQTY as FLOAT = NULL;
SELECT @CheckFindQTY = INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC WHERE INV_ID=@INV_ID AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION AND INV_QTY=@INV_QTY;

IF @CheckFindQTY is NULL
  SELECT @RecordFound = 3
```

Note that the test for a NULL value is `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work, it didn't pop up the alert message. Is it need to use execute scalar ?

Comment: @CaulsonChua - Your SQL doesn't return a value. You could use `select @CheckFindQty as CheckFindQty, @RecordFound as RecordFound` to return a single row with two columns. `ExecuteScalar` would give you the first value from the first row rather than the complete recordset.

Comment: Dear All, thanks for advise, i found out the solution use execute scalar.